# How do I pop to RootViewController when an alert is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Exercise Added", message: "\(name)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }
```

Within the IB action function of a button I have an alert, followed by some code to change to a different ViewController.

The program crashes upon reaching these lines of code after the alert:

***2016-01-04 17:48:27.147 FitnessApp[60584:4080964] popToViewController:transition: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.***

How do I run the code to change ViewController after the transition is done?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show the alert. And why does the code do a pop and a dismiss together?

Comment: if you are dismissing the viewController, why do you care about it's navigation stack?

Comment: The navigationcontroller is embedded in a modal.. I'm trying to go two levels back, to the 'home' screen

Comment: ok, but why are you dismissing the modal view controller then ?

Comment: OK, now you present the alert and then you immediately try to pop and dismiss. Don't you want to do the pop in the alert button handler?

Comment: @rmaddy When I put the code in the alert button handler, the same thing happens..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that you don't do anything with the alert button's handler. Instead, you immediately try to do the pop and dismiss after presenting the alert.

Move the code to pop the controller into the Ok button's alert handler.

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Exercise Added", message: "\(name)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        // You only need the pop
        //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note: I'm not fluent in Swift so the syntax could be off a little.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that's where the handler went!

Comment: Then what did you think the `handler` parameter was for? Glad I could help.

Comment: I thought the 'completion' parameter was the one i was supposed to implement..

The pop still doesn't go to the root though